# How do you create a js file that allows for global access to its functions in RoR 3.2+?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I created a javascript function in my application.js file for testing purposes but I am not able to access it when I use that function inline in my view files.

app/assets/application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function() {
  function test() {
    alert('test');
  }
}
```

views/layouts/application.html.haml

```
:javascript
  test(); // gives me a Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined error
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  test = function() {
    console.log("foo");
  }
});


// wait for document ready
$(document).ready(function() {
  test();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  window.test();
});
```

This will also fail

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var test = function() {
    console.log("foo");
  }
});
```

This should provide some good reading [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) as well.